Filling authors from a list using authblk does not work
I'm trying to write a class like this:
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/12/01]
\ProvidesClass{Bug}[2024/07/12 Bug]
\LoadClass[a4paper,twoside,openbib]{article}
\RequirePackage{expkv-opt}
\RequirePackage{expkv-def}
\ekvdefinekeys{myConf}{%
  store authors       = \myConf@authors,
  store organisations = \myConf@organisations,
  store title         = \myConf@title
}
\ekvoProcessLocalOptions{myConf}
\RequirePackage{expl3}
\RequirePackage{pgffor}
\RequirePackage{authblk}

\title{\myConf@title}

\newcounter{authorIndex}
\setcounter{authorIndex}{0}
\foreach \g in \myConf@authors {
  \stepcounter{authorIndex}
  \foreach \a in \g {
    \author[\the\value{authorIndex}]{\a}
  }
}

\newcounter{affIndex}
\setcounter{affIndex}{0}
\foreach \a in \myConf@organisations {
  \stepcounter{affIndex}
  \affil[\theaffIndex]{\a}
}

\renewcommand\Authsep{, }
\renewcommand\Authand{, }
\renewcommand\Authands{, }

in order to be able to use it like this :
\documentclass[
authors={{auth 1.1, auth 1.2},{auth 2.1},{auth 3.1}},
organisations={org 1, org 2, org 3},
title={Some title}
]{Bug}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
a lot of text
\end{document}

I would like to have all the authors separated by commas but I get this:

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong ?
Thanks,
Jouke

x-post https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/722418/36296
